# Windows 7 see cause of previous wake

Tags: windows-7, sleep, wake-up

Sometimes my machine wakes up by itself. I read about `powercfg -lastwake`, but this only shows the cause of the latest wake event.

Is there a way to look at a history of wake events and see their causes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the event viewer, EventID 1 with Source Power-Troubleshooter. Example:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter
Date:          07/09/2015 15:09:13
Event ID:      1
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      
User:          LOCAL SERVICE
Computer:      ****removed****
Description:
The system has resumed from sleep.

Sleep Time: ‎2015‎-‎09‎-‎07T13:03:46.363055300Z
Wake Time: ‎2015‎-‎09‎-‎07T13:09:09.983600800Z

Wake Source: Device -Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller
```

Comment: Aha! I see this `Wake Source: Timer - svchost.exe`

Comment: Does it show something behind svchost.exe in brackets to indicate which service is behind the svchost?

Comment: No, but I googled the message and people say one frequent cause is automatically scheduled windows updates. I checked my windows update settings and sure enough it is set to install at this time every night. I turned it off and it hasn't woken up by itself since. :)